# Difference between StreamingContext and JavaStreamingContext

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark and try to play around with the Streaming feature.

Therefore, I set up a java application that sends out random messages to the socket and with streamingContext I can grab this information. But then I had problems with the filter, and I have seen that I can use two different kinds of streamingContext modules, StreamingContext and JavaStreamingContext. In StreamingContext I can use the filter argument, but not in the  JavaStreamingContext.

Can someone tell me what is the difference and which should I use? I know a bit programming in C# and powershell, and right now I am using Scala.

Thanks

Stephan

Comment: JavaStreamingContext is used in Java, since you are in Scala use StreamingContext

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am really sorry for that noob question, but why can I even use it in Scala? Can I just mix Java with Scala like I wish?